# What is meant by rotate an eigenvector by a a complex phase $e^{i\theta_j}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices

> Exercise 1.3.1. Suppose that the eigenvalues $\lambda_1(A)>\ldots>\lambda_n(A)$ of an $n \times n$ Hermitian matrix are distinct. Show that the associated eigenbasis $u_1(A), \ldots, u_n(A)$ is unique up to rotating each individual eigenvector $u_j(A)$ by a complex phase $e^{i \theta_j}$. In particular, the spectral projections $P_j(A):= u_j(A)u_j(A)^*$ are unique. What happens when there is eigenvalue multiplicity?

In this question, what is meant by rotating an eigenvector $u_j(A)$ by $e^{i\theta_j}$? Is $e^{i\theta_j}$ just a complex number? Does this mean that the rotation works like this?

$$
\begin{aligned}
& e^{i (\hat{\theta}}\left[\begin{array}{l}
r_1 e^{i \theta_1} \\
r_2e^{i \theta_2} \\
r_3 e^{i \theta_3}
\end{array}\right] 
 =\left[\begin{array}{c}
r_1 e^{\left(i \theta_1+\hat{\theta}\right)} \\
r_2 e^{i\left(\theta_2+\hat{\theta}\right)} \\
r_3 e^{i\left(\theta_3+\hat{\theta}\right)}
\end{array}\right] \\
&
\end{aligned}
$$

This doesn't seem right to me, as I thought to represent a rotation, we need to represent this with a matrix. Is the author only describing the $\mathbb{C}^1$ case?

Comment: An eigenvector of a Hermitian matrix stays an eigenvector when you multiply it by an arbitrary scalar $z\in\mathbb C\,.$ When the eigenvalues are distinct that's all the freedom you have. When you want to preserve the lenght of the eigenvector all you can do is to multiply it with a purely imaginary $z$ (aka "phase"). Some people call this a rotation but this is not what it is geometrically in $\mathbb C^n\,.$

Comment: What we can say is that the components of the eigenvectors are rotated in the complex plane $\mathbb C\,.$